# Refreshing a ListView's adapter from inside an AsyncTask without duplicates

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-asynctask

I have a `ListView` and obviously an adapter the uses a `List<T>` object.
I added a button that is supposed to refresh the listview (= re-query the database and recreate the `ListView`).

All of the above (from querying the db to setting the adapter) happens inside an `AsyncTask`.

### Update Button Code

```
    mRefreshButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setClickable(false);
            new GetScheduleTask().execute((Void[]) null); //Basically, execute it again.
        }
    });
```

### AsyncTask (I deleted some unnecessary code)

```
    private class GetScheduleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Object[]>> {

        @Override
        protected List<Object[]> doInBackground(Void... params) {           
            SQLiteDatabase db = SchooLauncherDbHelper.getInstance(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();
            //TODO test repetition
            String sql = "LONG A** SQL HERE";

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {String.valueOf(cal.getTimeInMillis()), String.valueOf(cal.getTimeInMillis()),
                    String.valueOf(cal.getTimeInMillis()), String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))});

            while(c.moveToNext()) {
                ......................
                mEventList.add(new Object[] {new Class(...), new Subject(...)});
                }
            }

            db.close();
            return mEventList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Object[]> result) {
            mScheduleListView = (ListView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.mScheduleListView);

            TextView myTv = new TextView(getActivity());
            myTv.setText("No Results");
            mScheduleListView.setEmptyView(myTv);

            mScheduleEventAdapter = new ScheduleEventAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.schedule_item_layout, mEventList);
            mScheduleListView.setAdapter(mScheduleEventAdapter);

            if(!mImageView.isClickable())
                mImageView.setClickable(true);
        }
    }
```

### ScheduleEventAdapter

```
public class ScheduleEventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object[]>{

    private Context context; 
    private int layoutResourceId;    
    private List<Object[]> data = null;
    private View row = null;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Subject mSubject;
    private Event mEvent;
    private String mEventStartTime, mEventEndTime;

    public ScheduleEventAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Object[]> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            row = convertView;

            if(row == null) {
                inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(this.layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            }

            mSubject = (Subject) data.get(position)[1];
            mEvent = (Event) data.get(position)[0];
            ((ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.subjecticon)).setImageResource(mSubject.icon);
            ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.schedule_event_subject_name)).setText(mSubject.name);
            ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.schedule_event_title)).setText(mEvent.mEventTitle);
            ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.schedule_event_location)).setText(((Class)mEvent).mClassLocation);
            this.mEventStartTime = ((int) mEvent.mEventStartTime / (1000*60*60)) + ":" + ((int) (((mEvent.mEventStartTime / (1000*60)) % 60)));
            this.mEventEndTime = ((int) mEvent.mEventEndTime / (1000*60*60)) + ":" + ((int) (((mEvent.mEventEndTime / (1000*60)) % 60)));
            ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.schedule_event_time)).setText(this.mEventStartTime + " - " + this.mEventEndTime);

        return row;
    }
}
```

### The Problem

The problem is that the button works, but instead of re-creating the list, duplicates are being shown.

As you can see, new items are being added `mEventList`, even the ones that already show.
I could use an `if` statement with the `.contains()` method of the list to determine whether an object needs to be added to the list or not, but the problem is, even though the **contents** of the objects may be the same, the pointers are different which I guess is why it also doesn't work (I tried).

I also tried resetting the adapter and playing with the data and `.notifyDataSetChanged()` but it didn't work.

The only solution I could think of is to compare each field of each object inside the array, but that sounds too much like a performance-hit to me.

**If so, what would be the most efficient and correct way to fix this problem?**

Comment: Try to add mScheduleEventAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after setting the adapter in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: The duplicates are shown in first run, or when you clicked several times on your action button ?

Comment: @Szymon - Still the same...

Comment: @yurezcv - The duplicates show up after I click the button.

Comment: try to add this `mEventList.clear()` in `onPreExecute()` method of AsyncTask, or when button clicked. Good luck !